# How to extract supported XML Elements and Properties from a View?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-xml

Is there a way to extract the XML properties that a view supports? For example, an **EditText** has an XML property called *Text*, but on the Java side you use *getText* and *setText*.

I want to create a system that automatically discovers all the supported XML properties so I can verify the XML layout. At first just working with the default widgets is enough, but eventually I want to also enumerate custom widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Both standard and custom XML attributes are defined in `values/attrs.xml`. In the case of the built in ones they are in `android-sdk/platforms/android-X/data/res/values/attrs.xml`.

It looks to me like you would have to find a way to parse these files to figure out which attributes can be associated with which views.